# Are vendor prefixes still relevant for CSS3 features like box shadow and border radius?

Tags: css, browser, vendor-prefix

So whenever I need to do something like box shadow I write:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #EFDDCF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #EFDDCF;
box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #EFDDCF;
```

instead of just:

```
box-shadow: 0 3px 10px #EFDDCF;
```

Is this still necessary? It seems that both firefox and chrome still listen to normal "box-shadow" property. So even if I do this in Chrome for example:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px red;
box-shadow: 0 3px 10px green;
```

The box shadow color will be green and not red. So for which browser versions are the prefixes necessary?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to support older browser versions. As such, this is opinion based and thus off-topic for SO.

Comment: Just use autoprefixer and call it a day. you can configure how much backwards compatibility you need, using the caniuse api.   https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** if your want your webApp to run on

```
  Firefox 3.6-, Safari 4-,Android 2.3-,  or  iOS 3.2-
```

but today **you don't need it anymore**

and check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)

Comment: To confirm that these prefixes are no longer needed, all these versions are outdated since *Nov 2010* (``iOS 3.2`` ``Safari 4``), *Fev 2011* (``Android 2.3``) and *Jun 2011* (``FF 3.6``).